# How to use values from application.properties in named properties of annotations on class header

Tags: java, spring-boot

It is known that some annotations have named properties, such as:

```
@MyAnnotation(name="myName", url="http://www.example.com")
```

Now, if I were to use this annotation in `MyClass` like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(name="myName", url="http://www.example.com")
public class MyClass {
   ...
}
```

but move the values "myName" and "http://www.example.com" into application.properties like this:

```
services.name=myName
services.url=http://www.example.com
```

then how can I access these properties from `MyClass`?

I was able to use the properties defined in application.properties as below:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@MyAnnotation(name="${services.name}", url="${services.url}")
public class MyClass {
   ...
}
```

However, I am not sure if others can use `application.properties` values like this as well.

Comment: Binding named properties to values from *application.properties* and creating a custom annotation are two different concepts, not connected to each other. For binding properties check `@ConfigurationProperties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve binding using `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "services")
public class MyClass {
   private String name;
   private String url;
}
```

We use `@Configuration` so that Spring creates a Spring bean in the application context.

`@ConfigurationProperties` works best with hierarchical properties that all have the same prefix; therefore, we add a prefix of mail.

The Spring framework uses standard Java bean setters, so we must declare setters for each of the properties.

Note: If we don't use `@Configuration` in the POJO, then we need to add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class)` in the main Spring application class to bind the properties into the POJO:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyClass.class)
public class EnableConfigurationDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnableConfigurationDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring will automatically bind any property defined in our property file that has the prefix services and the same name as one of the fields in the `ConfigProperties class`.

References :

https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `@Value` annotation. For that your class must managed by `Spring`. In other words your class must be a `Spring Bean`.

Something like this,

```
@Service
public class MyClass {
   @Value("${services.name}")
   private String name;

   @Value("${services.url}")
   private String url;
}
```

*Note: For more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)*

You can also create custom configuration property class. Something like this,

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("services")
public class MyClass {
   private String name;
   private String url;
}
```

*Note: For more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)*